# Orbeon: integration with an external service via javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, integration, orbeon

I have a requirement to integrate an external API with Orbeon.
The API is supposed to retrieve a list of cities, streets and house numbers based on the postal code entered by the customer. Once the lists are retrieved, those autocomplete fields should be populated.

The issue I'm having with this is that the API is intended to be integrated by adding a reference to javascript code into the project.
The API in return calls their service and populates the fields based on specific IDs.

Would it somehow be possible to achieve this within Orbeon? To add the reference to the API and to populate the dropdown values of 3 autocomplete fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally you would do this by calling a REST API (using a service in Form Builder). Is there no REST API service available for the service you want to use? They really only provide a JavaScript API? If so, is this a public service that you could point us to?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. There have recently been discussions and we will be able to use the service. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Excellent Masha, I'm glad you'll be able to call a service instead of relying on a JavaScript API, and thank you for the update.